# Running the django admin over https using apache2

Tags: django, http, https, apache2, admin

I have a django web application that's running on apache 2.2.14 and I want to run the admin application over https.

Having read considerable discussions on using a proxy, writing middleware, running alternative wsgi scripts, the chaps in #httpd came to my rescue.  The solution is so simple, I was surprised I didn't find it online, so I'm curious to see if I've made some glaring assumptions or errors.

One complication was that I also wanted to run one of my django apps in the site over https, that is everything on /checkout.

Essentially, if a user requests a URI starting with /admin or /checkout on http, they are to be redirected to that URI but on https.  Conversely, if a user requests a URI that does not start with /admin or /checkout on https, they are to be redirected to that URI but on http.

The key to solving this problem was to use Redirect and RedirectMatch directives in my VirtualHost configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ... host config stuff ...

    Redirect /admin https://www.mywebsite.com/admin
    Redirect /checkout https://www.mywebsite.com/checkout

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ... ssl host config stuff ...

    RedirectMatch ^(/(?!admin|checkout).*) http://www.mywebsite.com$1

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to use `@secure_required decorator`. This will automatically rewrite the requested url and redirect to `https://...` version of the URL. Then you don't have to have Redirect in `*:80` configuration.  `*:443` configuration may still be required for performance purpose if you want other traffic to go through normal http traffic.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your solution, but ran into several problems. First, the formatting on the admin site disappeared, as if it could not find the admin static files. Second, if I tried to reach the non-admin site through https, the browser would not find it and redirect me to Yahoo search. Oddly, if I edited the yahoo search URL to eliminate all text except my correct URL (minus the `http://`), it would continue to search through yahoo for my site. However, typing the exact same URL afresh sent me to my site.

I solved all of these issues by simply removing the

```
RedirectMatch ^(/(?!admin|checkout).*) http://www.mywebsite.com$1
```

directive.

I should mention that I don't have a /checkout section on my site and am only trying to secure /admin.  ... and yes, I did substitute my URL for "mywebsite.com"

Answer (score 0):

What you described should work, but there may be a problem in the future if you need to make changes to which paths are/are not HTTPS. Because this method requires the ability to *correctly* modify the Apache config file it means you do *not* want novices in the loop. Screw up the config file and your site can go 500-error in the blink of an eye.

We chose to have a simple text file that had a list of the must-be-HTTPS paths. Anyone on the project can edit it and it is checked for correctness when it is loaded. We handle any needed redirects to/from HTTPS in middleware and it seems to work just fine. This method will also work if you are running anything *other* than Apache.